# .Net 6 core app on linux with strange behavior - requests pile up and then seem to process in batches

Tags: .net, linux, redis, .net-6.0

We have been running into a problem where we see slowdowns in request times when 1500 or more concurrent users beginning using our dotnet core backend. The max times can get into the 200 second range and can average around 4 seconds. The payload is not massive and is being cached via a local copy of Redis. The typical config is pretty common - Load balancer > Nginx reverse proxy > dotnet app. RAM and CPU are never exhausted on the server nor the DB. Bandwidth and I/O also don't seem to be an issue when looking at logging and metrics. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried running the app without nginx and only used kestrel and saw a slight performance increase without nginx, but the issue persists. I have also tried OS tuning (allowed more local ports and TCP/IP kernel changes). The nginx settings were also tuned based on best practices found on Github. What else should I be looking at? Also I'm not a dev :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!